# Android. Release build service not started

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have to weird behavior of application. 
In manifest I declare service with name

```
<service android:name="com.qwerty.SomeService" android:process=":qwerty"/>
```

When application worked in debug mode service started normally with no problem, but when application signed for release service not started. In case if I remove `android:process=":qwerty"` service also started normally in release build, but with process name no..

Device Nexus 7

I really puzzled. Please help me to solve this situation. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: check your proguard settings, test by turning off proguard for your release build

Comment: ok, I disable proguard and situation without changes